# Select Children of an Object With ForeignKey in Django?

Tags: python, django

I'm *brand new* to Django, so the answer to this is probably very simple. However, I can't figure it out.

Say I have two bare-bones Models.

```
class Blog(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=160)
    text = models.TextField()

class Comment(models.Model):
    blog = models.ForeignKey(Blog)
    text = models.TextField()
```

In the Python/Django shell, if I have a Blog object in a variable (say `blog = Blog.objects.get(id=3)`), how do I select all its child comments?

This doesn't seem to work: `blog.objects.all()`

Comment: should that be blog = models.ForeignKey(Blog)?

Comment: @second Oops! Yes, it should. Edited.

Answer (score 48, accepted):

to follow foreign keys 'backwards' you use

```
blog.comment_set.all()
```

Comment: I can't believe I passed that up on the Making Queries page in the documentation! Thank you!

Comment: Yes, but I thought the _set function was used on ManyToMany relationships for grabbing the list of ForeignKey parents, instead of the reverse of that.

Comment: Is there a way to prefetch all child elements ? It seems select_related or prefetch_related only works the other way around

Comment: I know this is an old question, but just wanted to mention that
`<model>_set` is the default, unless `related_name` is given on the child model. _"You can override the FOO_set name by setting the related_name parameter in the ForeignKey definition. "_ -- https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/db/queries/#backwards-related-objects