# How do I filter a query set based on child attributes after following a ForeignKey backwards?

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-queryset, django-orm

I'm new to Python/Django, so any help is much appreciated!

I am trying to find out a winner based on how many times score_1 > score_2 in all the child objects.

I have these two Models:

```
class Parent(models.Model):
   winner = models.IntegerField(default=0)

   def foo(self):
       childs_of_me = self.child_set.all()
       number_childs = childs_of_me.count()
       one_better = childs_of_me.filter(score_1__gt=score_2)
       one_wins_count = one_better.count()
       if one_wins_count > number_childs/2:
           self.winner = 1

class Child(models.Model):
   parent = models.ForeignKey(Parent, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
   score_1 = models.IntegerField(default=0)
   score_2 = models.IntegerField(default=0)
```

I've followed the answer to this Question([Select Children of an Object With ForeignKey in Django?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3535615/select-children-of-an-object-with-foreignkey-in-django)) to get child objects of a Parent object. However, I can't seem to figure out how to filter the returned set based on attributes in the Child Model.

```
one_better = childs_of_me.filter(score_1__gt=score_2)
```

returns an error: global variable score_2 unknown

How would I go about doing this?

Comment: Note, this question isn't really about foreign keys, but about comparing two fields on a model in a query.

Answer (score 2):

What you here want to do is reference *another field* as value in the queryset. You can do this by constructing an [**`F`-expression**](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/models/expressions/#f-expressions):

```
one_better = childs_of_me.filter(score_1__gt=F('score_2'))
```

Without doing this, Python interprets this as an identifier. Here we use a string, and wrap it around an `F`-object, to indicate that we want to refer to a field.