# Django ORM - get queryset of related items

Tags: python, django, orm

Consider the following models:

```
class Car(Model):
    owner = ForeignKey(User)
    ... some irrelevant attributes ...

class User(Model):
    # Django user model
```

Given a queryset of users, is there an easy way (e. g. one method call) how to get a queryset of cars which are owned by a user from the first queryset? Something like `User.objects.all().related("cars")`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use an `__in` lookup:

```
Car.objects.filter(owner__in=my_carz)
```

Comment: How many times will this hit the database? I am afraid twice, once for the `my_carz` queryset, and once for the actual query...

Comment: It depends. If the users queryset is not already evaluated, then this will be translated into a subquery so only one db hit. But note, be careful of over optimisation; whether it's one or two queries shouldn't make much difference.

Comment: Alright, this makes sense, will stick to this approach. Do you happen to have an idea why a method like my `related` does not exist? Is it on purpose, or just an accident?

Answer (score 0):

Here's a related stackoverflow answer hope it helps:
[fk backwards query](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3535615/select-children-of-an-object-with-foreignkey-in-django)

A naive implementations would be:

```
users = Users.objects.all()
for user in users:
    cars = user.car_set.all()
        ... do something with the cars queryset ...
```

Comment: This would be painfully slow